# what is a generic way to parse datatable information and use it in java

Tags: java, jquery, spring, datatables

I am sending datatable information as a json format then useing the information getting the database records. I just wanted to know is it a right way to make datatable information generic so that for all datatable related queries i can use same way. here is my try:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datatables.min.js"></script>


<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>FullName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th  >Action</th>  <!-- data-orderable="false" -->
            </tr>
        </thead>

        </table>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getDatatable();
} );
    var dt=null;
 function getDatatable(){
     if(dt){
         //dt.destroy();
     }
       dt= $('#example').DataTable( {
            processing: true,
            serverSide : true,
            //deferRender: true,
            order:  [[0, 'asc']],
            paging : true,
            //stateSave: true,
            "ajax": {
                url:"data-source",
                type:"POST",
                datatype : "json",
                 data: function(d){
                     console.log(d);
                     return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { data: "id" ,name:"id"},
                { data: "firstName",name:"firstName" },
                { data: "lastName",name:"lastName" },
                { data: "fullName",name:"fullName" },
                { data : function(o){
                    return o.email;
                },name:"email"
                },
                { "data": function(o1){ return "<input type='button' value='Ok' onclick='func1("+o1.id+",2)'>" }},
            ]
        } );

 }

 function func1(a,b){
     console.log(dt)
     console.log(a+"="+b);
     $.ajax({
         url:"check_update",
         data:{id:a},
         success:function(data){
             dt.draw(false);
         },error:function(dd){
             console.log(dd)
         }
     });

    //dt.page();
    //return "ee";
 }


</script>
</html>
```

datatable parsing utils class file code:

```
private Map<String, Object> parseDatatable(HttpServletRequest r) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Enumeration<String> obj = r.getParameterNames();
        String json = obj.hasMoreElements() ? obj.nextElement() : null;
        Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<>();
        if (json == null) {
            return m2;
        }
        System.out.println("json=" + json);
        Map<String, Object> m1 = g.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
        int draw = ((Double) m1.get("draw")).intValue();
        int startLimit = ((Double) m1.get("start")).intValue();
        int endLimit = ((Double) m1.get("length")).intValue();

        String searchKey = ((Map<String, String>) m1.get("search")).get("value");

        List<Map<String, Object>> order = (List<Map<String, Object>>) m1.get("order");
        int orderColumn = ((Double) order.get(0).get("column")).intValue();
        String orderBy = order.get(0).get("dir").toString();

        List<Map<String, Object>> columns = (List<Map<String, Object>>) m1.get("columns");

        //system.out.println(orderColumn+"="+columns.size());
        List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> m : columns) {
            String col=m.get("name").toString();
            //system.out.println(col);
            boolean searchable=(boolean)m.get("searchable");
            if(col.isEmpty()){
                col=m.get("data").toString();
            }
            if(!col.equalsIgnoreCase("function") && searchable)
            l1.add(col);
        }
        orderColumn=orderColumn<=(l1.size()-1)?orderColumn:0;


        m2.put("draw", draw);
        m2.put("startLimit", startLimit);
        m2.put("endLimit", endLimit);
        m2.put("searchKey", searchKey);
        m2.put("orderColumn", orderColumn);
        m2.put("orderBy", orderBy);
        m2.put("columns", l1);

        //system.out.println("m2=" + m2);
        return m2;
    }

    private String getSearchCondition(String searchKey,List<String> columns) {
        String where3=" WHERE ";
        for (int i=0;i<columns.size();i++) {
            if(i==columns.size()-1)
            where3+=columns.get(i)+" LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%' ";
            else
                where3+=columns.get(i)+" LIKE '%"+searchKey+"%' OR ";

        }   
        return where3;
    }
```

and the controller class code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data-source", method = { RequestMethod.POST,
        RequestMethod.GET }, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Object simpleJson1(HttpServletRequest r, @RequestBody String s)
        throws Employee1DaoException {
    //system.out.println("simpleJson1");
    ////system.out.println(s);

    Map<String, Object> m0 = parseDatatable(r);

    int draw = (int) m0.get("draw");
    int startLimit = (int) m0.get("startLimit");
    int endLimit = (int) m0.get("endLimit");
    String searchKey = (String) m0.get("searchKey");
    int orderColumn = (int) m0.get("orderColumn");
    String orderBy = (String) m0.get("orderBy");
    List<String> columns = (List<String>) m0.get("columns");

    String where1 = "",where2="",where3="";
    // //system.out.println(searchKey);
    if (searchKey != null && !searchKey.isEmpty() && !searchKey.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        where3 = getSearchCondition(searchKey,columns);//" WHERE ";

        //draw = 0;
    }
    where2 =where3+ " ORDER BY "+columns.get(orderColumn)+" "+orderBy+" limit " + (startLimit) + "," + endLimit;
    where1 =where3+ " ORDER BY "+columns.get(orderColumn)+" "+orderBy;

     //system.out.println(where1);
     //system.out.println(where2);
     //system.out.println(where3);

    int cnt = employee1Dao.findByQuery(where1).size();
    List<Employee1> le = employee1Dao.findByQuery(where2);
    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();

    for (Employee1 e1 : le) {
        if(e1.getId()==35){
            e1.setEmail("a@a");
        }
    }
    m1.put("draw", draw);
    m1.put("recordsTotal", cnt);
    m1.put("recordsFiltered", cnt);
    m1.put("data", le);

    return m1;
}
```

i want your suggestion so that i can make it common for all general datatable related operations.

Comment: At this stage I'd suggest making your code *clean* and *readable*, not *generic*. Once you clean it up some obvious patterns for improvements may appear which are simply invisible in this pile of... *mess* you have now.

Comment: @kryger: apart from Sop statements i didnt get any wrong and also it is commented(which may help u people for reference!). If u have suggestion then share.

Answer (score 3):

The following [library](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables) could maybe suit your needs.

Example:

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataTablesOutput<User> getUsers(@Valid DataTablesInput input) {
        return userRepository.findAll(input);
    }
}
```

Maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
     <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author :-)